# Jacobi Iteration in Fortran and MPI

Tags: matrix, fortran, mpi

I'm trying to solve ax=b with a jacobi iteration, my serial code works fine but the MPI version won't even run. can anyone help me?

Serial

```
program jacobis

implicit none

integer, parameter :: n=10
integer :: i,j,k,ni,s,seed
double precision :: tol,t1,t2,sig
double precision, dimension(0:n-1,0:n-1) :: A
double precision, dimension(0:n-1) :: B, x, xb, buff

ni=1000

seed=time()
call srand(seed)

do i=0, n-1
  do j=0, n-1
    A(i,j)=rand(0)
    B(i)=rand(0)
  end do
end do

do i = 0, n-1
 A(i,i) = sum(A(i,:)) + 1
enddo

!do i=0,n-1
 !A(i,i)=4
!end do  

print *, "a", A
print *, "b", B

x=B
call cpu_time(t1)
do k=1,ni
 xb=x
 do i=0,n-1
    s=0
    do j=0,n-1
    if (j/=i) then
         s=s+A(i,j)*xb(j)
        endif
    end do
    x(i)=(B(i)-s)/A(i,i) 

   sig=(x(i)-xb(i))*(x(i)-xb(i))
   tol=tol+sig
   tol=sqrt(tol)
 end do


 print *, "x", x

 !print *, "tol=", tol

 print *, "iter =",k

 if (tol<1.000001) EXIT
 if (k==(ni-1)) then
    print *, "Numero Maximo de Iteracoes" 
    EXIT
 endif
end do

 call cpu_time(t2)
 print *, "t=",t2-t1


end
```

MPI version

```
program jacobis

use mpi
implicit none

integer, parameter :: n=2
integer :: i_local,i_global,j,k,ni,s,m
double precision :: tol,t,t2,sig
double precision, dimension(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: A_local
double precision, dimension(:), ALLOCATABLE :: B_local, x_local, x_temp1,x_temp2,x_old,x_new, buff
INTEGER, DIMENSION (MPI_STATUS_SIZE) :: STATUS
integer :: rank,procs,tag,ierror


CALL MPI_INIT(ierror)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierror)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,procs,ierror)

ni=100
m=n/procs

ALLOCATE (A_local(0:n-1,0:n-1))
ALLOCATE (B_local(0:m-1))
ALLOCATE (x_temp1(0:m-1))
ALLOCATE (x_temp2(0:m-1))

A_local=0
B_local=2

do i_global=0,n-1
 A_local(i_global,i_global)=2
end do  

CALL MPI_ALLGATHER(B_local, m, MPI_DOUBLE, x_temp1, m, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)

x_new=x_temp1
x_old=x_temp2

print *, "a", A_local
print *, "b", B_local


t=mpi_wtime()
do k=1,ni
 x_old=x_new
 do i_local=0,m-1
    i_global=i_local+rank*m 
    !x_local(i_local)=b_local(i_local)
    s=0
    do j=0,n-1
    if (j/=i_local) then
         s=s+A_local(i_local,j)*x_old(j)
        endif
    end do
    x_local(i_local)=(B_local(i_local)-s)/A_local(i_local,i_global) 

 end do
 CALL MPI_ALLGATHER(x_local,m, MPI_DOUBLE, x_new, m, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)

 do i_global=0,n-1
   sig=(x_new(i_global)-x_old(i_global))*(x_new(i_global)-x_old(i_global))
   tol=tol+sig
   tol=sqrt(tol)
 end do

 print *, "x", x_local

 print *, "tol=", tol

 print *, "iter =",k

 if (tol<1.000001) EXIT
 if (k==(ni-1)) then
    print *, "Numero Maximo de Iteracoes" 
    EXIT
 endif
end do

 t2=mpi_wtime()-t;
 print *, "t=",t2

CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
end
```

can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong? Is it an index problem? Please i realy need to solve this today or i'll flunk the course. I've spent countless hours on this and can't make it work.

Ok you were right! Now i have a segmentation fault, but can't find it! have replaced the code with the new version

Comment: You still have non-allocated arrays on the LHS of assignment expressions. What compiler are you using? Compile with `-O0 -g -C` flags to obtain error messages with more hints about what's wrong. Because this is a class assignment, we cannot debug your code, but can only give hints about what is wrong and how to proceed. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, now it calculates the iteration correctly, proven by the serial program using the same matrix. It was an allocation and index problem. Thanks to the previous answer, was very helpfull.

```
program jacobis

use mpi
implicit none

integer, parameter :: n=1000
integer :: i_local,i_global,j,k,ni,s,m,seed
double precision :: tol,t,t2,sig
double precision, dimension(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: A_local
double precision, dimension(:), ALLOCATABLE :: B_local, x_local, x_temp1,x_old,x_new, buff
INTEGER, DIMENSION (MPI_STATUS_SIZE) :: STATUS
integer :: rank,procs,tag,ierror


CALL MPI_INIT(ierror)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierror)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,procs,ierror)

ni=1000
m=n/procs

ALLOCATE (A_local(0:n-1,0:n-1))
ALLOCATE (B_local(0:n-1))
ALLOCATE (x_local(0:n-1))
ALLOCATE (x_temp1(0:n-1))
ALLOCATE (x_new(0:n-1))

!A_local=23
!B_local=47

seed=time()
call srand(seed)

do k=0, n-1
 do j=0, n-1
    A_local(k,j)=rand(0)
    B_local(k)=rand(0)
 end do
end do

do i_global = 0, m-1
 A_local(i_global,i_global) = sum(A_local(i_global,:)) + n
enddo

CALL MPI_ALLGATHER(B_local, m, MPI_DOUBLE, x_temp1, m, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)

x_new=x_temp1

print *, "a", A_local
print *, "b", B_local


t=mpi_wtime()
do k=1,ni
 x_old=x_new
 do i_local=0,m-1
    i_global=i_local+rank*m 
    !x_local(i_local)=b_local(i_local)
    s=0
    do j=0,n-1
    if (j/=i_local) then
         s=s+A_local(i_local,j)*x_old(j)
        endif
    end do
    x_local(i_local)=(B_local(i_local)-s)/A_local(i_local,i_global) 
 end do
 CALL MPI_ALLGATHER(x_local,m, MPI_DOUBLE, x_new, m, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)
 do j=0,n-1
   sig=(x_new(j)-x_old(j))*(x_new(j)-x_old(j))
   tol=tol+sig
   tol=sqrt(tol)
 end do

 print *, "x", x_local

 print *, "tol=", tol

 print *, "iter =",k

 if (tol<1.01) EXIT
 if (k==(ni-1)) then
    print *, "Numero Maximo de Iteracoes" 
    EXIT
 endif
end do

 t2=mpi_wtime()-t;
 print *, "t=",t2

CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
end
```

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. Note that you can click on the check mark to accept either answer as correct.

Comment: Think about clicking the check mark on the answer from @IRO-bot, which helped you solve the problem (not your own solution that was based on his suggestion).

Answer (score 2):

Your program has several issues that I can see. The error message that you included indicates a non-allocated receive buffer in this call:

```
CALL MPI_ALLGATHER(B_local, m, MPI_DOUBLE, x_temp1, m, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
```

Array `x_temp1`, the receive buffer, needs to be allocated before using in this context.

Fixing this would only get you as far, and you will get a less informative Segmentation Fault. It will be useful to look up correct usage for `MPI_AllGather` in your MPI implementation. Most MPI routines have an integer error status argument at the end:

```
MPI_ALLGATHER(SENDBUF, SENDCOUNT, SENDTYPE, RECVBUF, RECVCOUNT,
        RECVTYPE, COMM, IERROR)
    <type>    SENDBUF (*), RECVBUF (*)
    INTEGER    SENDCOUNT, SENDTYPE, RECVCOUNT, RECVTYPE, COMM,
    INTEGER    IERROR
```

This should get you going with your assignment. Make sure to allocate all `allocatable` arrays that you use, and to use appropriate documentation for your MPI implementation and compiler manual.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has a serious issue and you may be getting wrong results. Variable s is declared as integer, while it is assigned non-integer values. Redeclare it as double precision to get correct results. (Posted for those who ever copy this code)